# In digital electronics, is the essence of "on/off" states driven solely by chemically-doped silicon?

Tags: transistors, current, clock, flipflop, semiconductors

I believe that in digital electronics, such as those measured in binary, we use semiconductor-doped amplifiers to switch electrical signals around. In the simplest sense we could split one analog signal in to two constituent parts of a wave ... on and off. This would be a simple "yes" or "no" circuit, whereas "yes" may mean to turn the LED on, and "no" may mean to turn it off (i.e. no current to flow).

My question is, is the essence of "intelligent machines", such as microprocessors of today, just the result of additional amplification dopants that can modify larger volumes of electrons, and provide faster amplification?

We know that in older microprocessors they had smaller bit-width, so they had less transistors, and their clocks were slower as well.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your question, and the last sentence is a mystery to me too. On second reading, the first paragraph doesn't make any sense either. For starters, semiconductor material is doped (not semiconductor-doped), and the result is MOSFETS, which can be indeed arranged as an amplifier, but in a computer they are generally not used in that way (main exception: sense amplifiers in DRAM and FLASH).

Comment: Amplification dopants? Modifying larger volumes of electrons? Faster amplification? Have these peculiar terms come thru an on-line translation service?

Comment: Please note that binary circuits operate on "HI/LO" system, which isn't necessarily the same same as "ON/OFF".

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Actually, most of the transistors in digital logic *are* operating as amplifiers, in the sense that they're controlling more power than it takes to control them (i.e., fanout > 1). If this were not the case, it would be difficult to build logic circuits of more than trivial complexity.

Comment: You have apparently heard a few terms related to electronics and semiconductors, which you are now throwing about in a non-sensical way.  There are too many assumptions built into your "question" so make unrevelling this mess tractable here.  Even then, it's not clear you'd understand the answer.  Either ask simple individual basic questions, or learn more electronics before trying to make complex assertions or ask complex questions.

Comment: This question looks like text that was generated by an "intelligent" computer program. It's better than "word-salad" quality, yet I can't make heads or tails out of it.

Comment: All aboard the HMS HMM!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ^ Hidden model sequences; hidden markov models? ;)

Comment: @Kaz: Her Majesty's Ship Hidden Markov Models.

Comment: @Ignacio: sounds like a Culture's ship to me.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is the essence of "intelligent machines", such as
>   microprocessors of today, just the result of additional amplification
>   dopants that can modify larger volumes of electrons, and provide
>   faster amplification?

In a word, *no*.  Frankly, this *almost* reaches the level of gibberish but is not nearly as entertaining as [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLDgQg6bq7o).